# How do we create a simple GUI app with glade and C?

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3, glade

As I am new to glade and C, I am trying to build a very simple GUI which has an entry box a label and a button. When the button is pressed whatever values present in the text box will we show it in label. This is my glade,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Generated with glade 3.22.1 -->
<interface>
  <requires lib="gtk+" version="3.20"/>
  <object class="GtkWindow" id="windows1">
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <child>
      <placeholder/>
    </child>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkFixed">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkButton" id="button1">
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">button</property>
            <property name="width_request">100</property>
            <property name="height_request">80</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">True</property>
            <property name="receives_default">True</property>
            <signal name="clicked" handler="on_clicked" swapped="no"/>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="x">182</property>
            <property name="y">146</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkEntry" id="entry1">
            <property name="width_request">100</property>
            <property name="height_request">80</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">True</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="x">68</property>
            <property name="y">45</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkLabel" id="label1">
            <property name="width_request">100</property>
            <property name="height_request">80</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">False</property>
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">label</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="x">321</property>
            <property name="y">44</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>
```

And this is the  C logic which on button press prints `clicked` in terminal.

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

void on_clicked(GtkButton * b, gpointer data)
{
    (void)b;
    (void)data;
    printf("clicked");
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    GtkBuilder      *builder;
    GtkWidget       *window;

    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    builder = gtk_builder_new();
    gtk_builder_add_from_file (builder, "example.glade", NULL);

    window = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "window1"));

    gtk_builder_connect_signals(builder, NULL);

    g_object_unref(builder);

    gtk_widget_show(window);
    gtk_main();

    return 0;
}

// called when window is closed
void on_window_main_destroy()
{
    gtk_main_quit();
}
```

I compiled the c code without any error using

```
gcc main.c $(pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0) -o main -export-dynamic
```

But when I run I get this warning but no gui

> Gtk-CRITICAL **: : gtk_widget_show: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed

How can I solve this problem? The second question is how can I fetch values from the text box and show it in label using c.

Answer (score 1):

The error message you're getting is because your GtkWindow has id `"windows1"`, while you're trying to fetch it using id `"window1"` (note that the former has an 's' in the middle, while the latter doesn't).

For your other question: you should fetch the GtkEntry widget (also using `gtk_builder_get_object()`) and save the resulting pointer somewhere. You can then fetch its contents once you are inside your callback.